# asp Textbox & HTML Input - Values always empty

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp Textbox for a username and a HTML input for a password, these are both server controls and are contained in the master page (in a modal popup).

```
<input runat="server" Class="login-input" id="txtPassword" placeholder="Password" type="password"
<asp:Textbox style="float:left; margin-right:25px;" runat="server" id="txtUsername" Class="login-input" Placeholder="Username" name="txtUserName"/>
```

I also have a login button hooked up to a handler in the code behind. However the value of the 2 input boxes is always empty.

I had to include UseSubmitBehavior="False" on my button as this was the only way i could get my click event to

```
<asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="False" runat="server" Class="login-button" ID="btnLogin" Text="Login" />
```

Not sure what's going on here, i have checked my code and definitely only have 1 form tag, which i heard can cause this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that at runtime my modal was not contained within the  tags.

Therefore i had to use

```
$('#divname').parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
```

within my script to move the elements back within the form tags.
(There were 2 modal elements outside) I found this out by using f12 dev tools/firebug.