# Href to an element in another page

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

As alternative to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362831/asp-textbox-html-input-values-always-empty)

I have a link in my page.Master, i would like to link the href attribute to an element which is contained in another page (Main.aspx)

```
<li><a href="#modal" id="login">Login</a></li>
```

The code above works if the modal element is placed within the master page, however the modal being in the master page causes problems. I have now placed the modal in a different page, can i still call it to be opened from the master page?

I have tried -

```
<li><a href="Main.aspx/#modal" id="login">Login</a></li>
```

However this does not work

or is this not possible?

Comment: I already have tried with the code i have posted. This is why im now asking as it did not work

Comment: Ah, You forgot to tell us that. So some modal thing is looking at the hash and popping a window?

Comment: Yea i had the modal in the same page as i was calling it from, which worked fine but caused problems with events, so now I've moved the modal to another page and would like to call it

Comment: If you detail  the problems perhaps we could help you fix them instead of kluging them?

Comment: The problems are in another question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362831/asp-textbox-html-input-values-always-empty Been trying to sort them for too long so just decided it was easier to move the modal

Comment: Did you try `href="Main.aspx#modal"`? (no slash)

Comment: I think you're right there, however it still doesn't work. There must be something else going wrong somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Can I assume than the main.aspx is a child page of you master page?
If so

As a general Concept you can pass data from Child to master because child code executed before the master code.
What I normally do is set a session value

within the child load section:

```
session("send2Master") = "data to be sent;
```

and collect it in the master within the Master load section.

```
string dataInMaster = session("send2Master").tostring();
session.remove("send2Master");
```

If your data is only available on child postback event,
you can still send data to the master in the prerender master event.
once your data is in the master code you can use it in any control in the master.
As this is a hyperlink it is even simpler as there is no worries about data being available for postback event in master.

Comment: I did find a solution eventually, i had to use "MainContent_#modal" the Id was being changed at runtime for some reason. However i managed to structure my page in a different way and avoided the problem completely. Thanks for the detailed answer though, i didn't know you could pass data between main & master that easily. It will come in useful